# matlab and Python in numeric calculations

Tags: python, matlab

I am kind of new in Python. I am trying to convert some MATLAB code to Python. This MATLAB code uses a lot of arrays, such as x = [-0.22258   0.50889  -0.35733  -0.22992  -0.26910]. I need to do all kinds of mathematical operations on these arrays, e.g. +/-/* and division. What is the best way to express an array of numbers in Python for this purpose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-0.22258, 0.50889, -0.35733, -0.22992, -0.26910])
```

For instance:

```
x = np.array([-0.22258, 0.50889, -0.35733, -0.22992, -0.26910])
y = np.array([10,9,8,7,6])

>>> x/y
array([-0.022258  ,  0.05654333, -0.04466625, -0.03284571, -0.04485   ])

>>> x+y
array([ 9.77742,  9.50889,  7.64267,  6.77008,  5.7309 ])

>>> x-y
array([-10.22258,  -8.49111,  -8.35733,  -7.22992,  -6.2691 ])
```

and ***LOTS*** of much more complicated numerical computation capabilities. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/) says it all.

As a side note, since it seems you're a `MATLAB` user, you can take a look at this [NumPy for MATLAB users](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html) conversion table, I used it quite a bit to get me started when I was translating an algorithm from MATLAB to Python.

Comment: This doesn't work with Python3.3. Is there a solution for Python3.3?

Comment: It's one of the most widely used python packages, and should work for any recent python, including 3.3, it's probably just that you don't have it installed. Try `pip install numpy` from your command prompt (not in your `python` interperter), assuming you have pip installed. Here's a [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html) to get your installation running

Comment: No matter where I run pip in the command window, I always got "pip is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." However, in Python window, it is confirmed that 'pip' was installed. Any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: then you'll need to [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). In any case, if you want to install basically *any* package in python, you'll find that pip is the easiest way to go, or, you could use a python distribution from anaconda, which is bundled with many popular packages.